# labelling distinct elements of a column

Tags: mysql

Below is the table of animals on various floors.

ID,FLOOR_LEVEL,ANIMAL *[column names]*

01,A,CAT
02,A,DOG
03,B,DOG
04,B,CAT
05,B,CAT
06,C,CAT

I want to label the types of animal(i.e cat will be labelled as 1, dog will be labelled as 2....) like shown below by creating a new column LABEL.

ID,FLOOR_LEVEL,ANIMAL,LABEL *[column names]*

01,A,CAT,1
02,A,DOG,2
03,B,DOG,2
04,B,CAT,1
05,B,CAT,1

06,C,CAT,1

It can be done by writing query such as
INSERT INTO table_name (LABEL)
VALUES (1,2,2,1,1,1);

But, how can this be generalised for a huge no. of different type of animals in MySQL by writing query? Please help.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the existing labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is **not** a numeric label, try using `md5()` to generate a hash label for the animals. Its value would be same for animals with same name (case sensitive).

```
SELECT ID, FLOOR_LEVEL, ANIMAL, MD5(UPPER(ANIMAL))
FROM table;
```

Please note that `MD5()` string are case sensitive. i.e. `DOG` and `Dog` would generate a different output, hence I have used `UPPER()` method.

Another option is to use below function, which will convert the alphanumeric `md5()` value to a long type. But the numeric value would not be starting from 1, 2 etc.

```
cast(conv(substring(md5(upper(animal)), 1, 16), 16, 10) as unsigned integer)
```

**EDIT - Based on OP comment**

> But is there any way to reduce the length of generated values?

To reduce the length of the generated value, Use `rand()` function wisely to reduce the length of the integer. The only concern is that you may not want a collision of generated values.

```
round(cast(conv(substring(md5(upper(animal)), 1, 16), 16, 10) as unsigned integer) * (rand() * rand()))
```

A more sophisticated, optimized and non-colliding value may be generated using Hive `UDF`.

Comment: thanks, it really helped. But is there any way to reduce the length of generated values?

Comment: @MKK Added some option usind `rand()` function. Please do not forget to upvote and accept if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT statement makes no sense:

```
 INSERT INTO table_name (LABEL) VALUES (1,2,2,1,1,1);
```

Will insert 1 row into a table called table_name with 6 columns. It would do nothing for you.

Instead make a new table to store the animal `id` and animal `name`:

```
CREATE TABLE animals ( id int, animal_name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO animals VALUES (1, 'cat'),(2, 'dog'),(3,'tardigrade'),(4,'liger');
```

And then join that into your query:

```
SELECT t1.floor_level, t1.animal, t2.id
FROM table t1
    INNER JOIN animals t2 ON
        t1.animal = t2.animal_name;
```

Optionally you could use a case statement to do this within the query. It will get a little laborious if you have a ton of animals though. And you will have to rewrite it every time you query this table.

```
SELECT floor_level, 
  animal, 
  CASE WHEN animal = 'cat' THEN 1 
    WHEN animal = 'dog' THEN 2 
    WHEN animal = 'tardigrade' THEN 3 
    WHEN animal = 'liger' THEN 4 
    END as animal_id
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is CASE

```
SELECT ID, FLOOR_LEVEL, ANIMAL,
CASE
 WHEN ANIMAL = 'CAT' THEN 1
 WHEN ANIMAL = 'DOG' THEN 2
END
FROM table;
```

Comment: Here also i need to write the name of all animals. Isn't there any way which will group each type of animal and assign them a particular class.

Comment: The straight forward thing would be to left join your table with a grouped by and numerated version of itself.
  
To get a grouped by version just use:
    "SELECT ANIMAL
    GROUP BY ANIMAL
    FROM table;"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve your problem is with a DECODE

```
SELECT
 DECODE( 
 ANIMAL,
 'CAT',1,
 'DOG',2,
 'OTHER'
 )
 FROM ...
```

Here is more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm

Good Luck!